# Why is linkedIn adding a pound exclamation mark (hashbang) to my URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, linkedin-api, social-networking, linkedin-jsapi

When sharing a link I've noticed that linkedIn appends a '#!' to the end of the URL after redirecting.  This is breaking my Backbone.js single-page app since we use pushstate in the URL, and so the '!' is interpreted as a Backbone.js route.

Here is an example [link](http://www.linkedin.com/nhome/nus-redirect?url=http://blog.mindresearch.net/blog/bid/336633/The-Connection-Between-Math-and-Neuroscience&urlhash=ueds&trkToken=action=viewArticle&pageKey=uscp-home&contextId=8d7b3684-9e3f-4e0f-9d22-1e32ba473a12&isSponsored=false&distanceFromViewer=1&aggregationType=none&isPublic=true&verbType=linkedin%3ashare&activityId=activity:5788408314098360320&isDigested=false&isFolloweeOfPoster=false&actorType=linkedin%3amember&feedPosition=16&actorId=member:1189742&objectId=article:5786532896000974883&rowPosition=1&objectType=linkedin%3aarticle&goback=.nmp_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1&trk=object-title) (not my site).  It will take you to:
http://blog.mindresearch.net/blog/bid/336633/The-Connection-Between-Math-and-Neuroscience#!

I know I can filter this on the server-side, or deal with it on the client-side in numerous ways, but it just seems strange, and I saw no posts online about this topic, so thought I'd post a question asking what it is, and whether there is a way to get rid of it?

Of course, I'll also email LinkedIn support, but thought this could be useful to anyone else running into the same problem.

Comment: That's the way it is, Facebook does the same. Get over it.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK anything after the hash is not sent to the server; I use a simple client-side script to redirect those URLs. A naive redirect, but it works. I don't see any way of preventing it from occurring, unless LinkedIn and Facebook change their outgoing redirect policy.

```
<script>
  if( window.location.hash == '#!' ) {
    window.location.href = 'http://domain.tld/';
  }
</script>
```

Sure it only works for JavaScript enabled clients, but then again in my experience those hashbang URLs only break those clients in the first place.